# Stream Video with FastAPI on Multi-Threaded Python Function

Tags: python, multithreading, deployment, fastapi

I am working on a YoloV4 model for multi class Object Detection, which is a multi-threaded function, 3 threads to be precise. 1st thread will take care of reading the frames, 2nd thread takes care of detections and 3rd thread marks the detection on the frame and writes it for output.

Now I am trying to deploy this model with FastAPI, the problem is after days of research all I can see is the StreamingResponse is used only when there's one function which does all the job. So can anyone suggest me on how to approach this.